# Cannot read property 'clientHeight' of null - working JSfiddle tutorial won't work anywhere else?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

I'm following a tutorial that is trying to teach me how to setup a basic THREE.js scene and add animation keyframes that are triggered when scrolling. Inside of fiddle, i understand the way keyframes work and was able to get a result i liked. I tried to recreate the fiddle on my own website, but this error keeps getting thrown.

I checked other questions/answers that are similar to this but couldn't find a fix.

On line 17 of my 'index.js' I get an "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property: 'clientHeight' of null**"

HTML showing div 'container':

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/three.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>



  <div class='webgl'></div>
  <div class='container'></div>


  <span></span>



  </body>
</html>
```

Line 17, where clientHeight throws an error

```
var maxHeight = (divContainer.clientHeight || divContainer.offsetHeight) - window.innerHeight
```

Here is a working [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/onirenaud/p86wzh9v/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=p86wzh9v) that i'm trying to use as a starting point for my own project. 
Here is the [original tutorial](https://codeburst.io/scroll-based-animate-timeline-with-easing-functions-on-a-webgl-scene-ef7c3f5a8d9b) i was working from.

EDIT: Full [index.js](https://controlc.com/02dee8c4) & Full [index.html](https://controlc.com/a770b2b3)

Comment: divContainer is null--wouldn't it make sense to at least include the code where you initialize it? Including whether or not you're waiting for dom-ready.

Comment: I'm new to javascript and trying to learn. I think i should have phrased this differently. Maybe: 'What is the process of moving a working project from JSFiddle to my own website?' - I'm still trying to wrap my head around what is 'missing' from the fiddle code i'm seeing. My method was to link to the relevant js and css files before the body in my HTML file. Index.js is where i've copied the JS from the fiddle. I don't know where I initialise it (i know it's frustrating, i'm trying to learn) - i can upload the full code. Or alternatively, i could ask a new more relevant question about fiddle?

Comment: Try moving `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>` to the line before the closing `</body>` tag. 
Also, you might have missed it out of the code, but does your page have an opening `<html>` tag (above the `<head>` tag)?

Comment: Yeah html tag is there, but moving it worked.. I'm not sure i know why it worked but it did so thank you @danlong

Comment: It works because your `index.js` logic is now running after the div creation (specifically, the one in your code that you're trying to get the height of). Does that make sense?

Comment: I spent a whole five hours today banging my head against the table. It does now make sense, I always feel like i'm playing catchup with javascript logic. I didn't consider *when* i was asking for things to happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this instance, to fix the problem you can simply move the `index.js` file to right above the closing `</body>` tag.

The code inside index.js isn't waiting for the document to finishing loading before trying to reference the div which doesn't exist at time of execution. Hence the error.

There's a few different ways to fix this, defer script loading, running your JS logic inside a document ready type function to name a few. It's worth reading up on if you have the time :)

Comment: Don't feel like a dummy, it happens to us all! It's usually because people have had this problem before that they know how to fix it :)